# Firebase Functions predeploy parsing error run lint

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

When i try to deploy my Firebase Functions it gets an parse error.
I am using cmd on Windows and i am coding in JavaScript.
A couple of days ago i deployed my Functions on Mac and it worked, today i wanted to do the same thing on windows. After i tried it on Windows and it didn't worked, i tried it on mac again and it did not worked eather, even if it worked before.

I tried to change the firebase.json from "predeploy":[
"npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint"
]
to:
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint"
]

but this was alos not working.

Can anybody help me out here?
Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your lint file to account for the new ECMA script. Add the `ecmaVersion` key-value pair to your `eslintrc.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020, // add this
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ]
};
```